# Set Google Cloud Run environment variables value based on another environment variable

Tags: environment-variables, google-cloud-run

As far as I understand Google Cloud Run sets a **$PORT** environment variable by itself that my application should try to run on.
Let's say my application wants to start on **$PORT2**.
Can I define on the Google Cloud Run Environment Variables page (or elsewhere) that **$PORT2** envvar should take the value of **$PORT**?
Obviously the other solution would be to change my application start on **PORT**, am just curious if this is possible?
Thanks

Comment: AFAIK, no, it's not possible. The use case is strange not? What are your requirements/needs?

Comment: It's been 2 years and 6months, and there is still no way to do this within CloudRun. 
This is especially frustrating because some frameworks(such as Prisma) absolutely NEED a connection string containing a password. In this case, I would like to set an environment variable that references another environment variable I am sourcing as a secret. It's impossible to do this by purely using the CloudRun manifest files. I had to use the `env` command inside the entrypoint script.

Answer (score 3):

You can pretty much only achieve it by changing your container's entrypoint to a program (e.g. `env`) that re-adjusts the environment variables to your program:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/sh", "-c", "env PORT2=$PORT ./your-app"]
```

Try it:

```
docker run --rm -e PORT=8080 busybox /bin/sh -c 'env PORT2=$PORT env'
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I also couldn't find a way to do this cleanly.

[Kubernetes has this feature](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/define-environment-variable-container/#using-environment-variables-inside-of-your-config), but it doesn't translate into Google CloudRun.

My use case is that I need to reference a *secret* environment variable inside another environment variable that I am defining. Ultimately, I had to set the variable in the `commands` list inside the CloudRun Job manifest, like so:

```yaml
commands: ['/bin/sh', '-c', 'env DATABASE_URL=postgres://$DB_USER:$DB_PASSWORD@$DB_HOST:5432/test?schema=public yarn prisma migrate dev'],
```

`DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD`, and `DB_HOST` are specified normally under the `envs:` section when creating the CloudRun Job:

```yaml
        envs: [
          {
            name: 'DB_HOST',
            value: idpAlloyDbInstance.ipAddress,
          },
          {
            name: 'DB_USER',
            value: config.require('dbUser'),
          },
          {
            name: 'DB_PASSWORD',
            valueSource: {
              secretKeyRef: {
                secret: alloyDbPassword.id,
                version: '1',
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      }]
```

I imagine it works similarly for CloudRun Services.

Hope this was helpful!